# Creating a tableView on each cycle of for loop. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a tableView for each value in my array and I am not sure how to go about creating that. The code below clearly doesn't work I just used it to illustrate my point. How do I differentiate between tables in the tableView protocol functions.

```
let array = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

for value in array{

    let newTableView: UITableView()
    //Continue with creation of table 
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableContent.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    return cell
}
```

Any help is appreciated and please comment if the question is unclear

Comment: Why would you want a table view per single value in an array? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: A whole table view for each entry in an array? That doesn't really make sense to me. Table views are meta-objects, that manage arrays of cells (or even arrays of arrays of objects, in the case of a sectioned table view.) Why would you want a whole array of table views? Like rmaddy, I'd like to hear about your actual goal before helping you do something so unlikely sounding.

Comment: I am allowing a user to create an event in his location with a hundred meter radius and allowing anyone in this radius to post an image. So lets say there is 4 events in the same location, I would want each table to represent an event and the rows represent the post in the event so that the user can view all the posts; if that makes any sense @DuncanC

Comment: Use one TableView multiple data sources

Comment: could you please provide an example @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I have needed multiple TableViews or Collection Views in a single ViewController, e.g. for different tabs.

You can identify each table by using the tag property.

```
let data : [Int : [YourObjects]]

for key, value in data {

    let newTableView: UITableView()
    // Identify the table
    newTableView.tag = key
    newTableView.dataSource = self

    //Continue with creation of table 
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.data[tableView.tag].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue cell
    // Get the data for this table, identified by the tag
    let tableData = data[tableView.tag]
    cell.populateCell(withData: tableData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```